# caught TypeError: $(...).stop is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I have this following code:

```
setInterval(function() {
 $(".custom-banner").stop().slideToggle('slow');
 }, 5000);
 $(".custom-close").click(function() {
   $(".custom-banner").stop().slideToggle('slow');
 });
```

I always get the error in the console

> caught TypeError: $(...).stop is not a function

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `$(".custom-banner")` is not what you think it is, do some debugging on what it returns.

Comment: Use jQuery. It should be looks like. ```jQuery(document).ready(function($){ //Place your code here. });``` It's enable to read "$".

Comment: @Newbee this is not true

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a [mcve].